# How to fix the COM issue in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have a problem when converting the word to pdf using Microsoft Interop COM object.I am getting when the applciation is hosted in local IIS. [image]

I have googled alot but no use can any one help me on this ?

Comment: Please show your work and exception message as a text.

Comment: I am uploading the doc file and trying to convert to pdf using Microsoft interop.

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services) ..."

Comment: So can't make this accessed ?

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.